# How to make an accessible image selection checkbox

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a grid of images, which the user can select by clicking anywhere on them, similar to selecting images in a photos app like Google Photos:

[image: Screenshot of image grid]

Are there any accessibility issues with the following markup / can it be improved in any way?

```
<label for="image-checkbox-1">
  <span class="labelText">Select Image 1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="image-checkbox-1">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" />
</label>
```

Note that the text is hidden by CSS using font-size:0, but this is not really part of the question, I'm more concerned with whether or not wrapping an image inside a checkbox label is good practice or not.

Comment: Read this [<label>: The Input Label element#Accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label?retiredLocale=nl#accessibility_concerns)

Comment: The accessibility concerns in that article talk about putting interactive elements inside a `<label>`.  It doesn't address putting an `<img>` in a `<label>`.

Comment: What does the magnifying glass signify? Are there two actions bound to the image? Maybe that’s what @RenevanderLende was worried about.

Comment: Good point @Andy, in the real code the magnifying glass is a button that currently also sits inside the label so since it’s an interactive element I’ll need to put it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That practice should be ok.

As per [Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.2](https://w3c.github.io/accname/), the `<label>`’s contents become the `<input>`’s name.

While computing the name

- contents of `alt` attributes get included in the name computation
- hidden elements get excluded (the span)

So when focusing your checkbox, a screen reader would announce

> image description, checkbox, unchecked

Could you do something better?

- Remove your `for` attribute, as it’s redundant with wrapping the input inside the label
- Remove the `<span>` entirely, as `font-size: 0` also hides it from screen readers. So it’s simply hidden from everybody
- Provide `width` and `height` attributes for the images, so that the browser can reserve the correct space while images are still being loaded

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="100" height="200" />
</label>
```

If you do want to provide extra text for assistive technology, but not include it in the image alt text, you should use [a tested CSS class like `visually-hidden`](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html).